# Oracle Database 18c Configuration Assistant failed

Tags: oracle

My installation of Oracle Database 18c stuck at 71% with error code Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed. I am using Windows 10 x64
Here is error from log file:

```
Instance created.
DIM-00019: create service error
O/S-Error: (OS 1387) You cannot add or remove a new group member from the local group because this group member does not exist.
DBCA_PROGRESS : 12%
[ 2020-01-02 13:38:04.012 CET ] [FATAL] ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

DBCA_PROGRESS : 40%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 100%
[ 2020-01-02 13:38:04.020 CET ] [FATAL] ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this error keep DCA open, go to the windows services and start by hand the oracle service. When started your installation should continue further.

Comment: After starting oracle service by hand, there appears to be another problem when try to retry installation:WARNING] [DBT-10328] Specified GDB Name (orcl) may have a potential conflict with an already existing database on the system.
   ACTION: Specify a different GDB Name that does not conflict with existing databases on the system.
[FATAL] [DBT-10317] Specified SID Name (orcl) already exists.
   ACTION: Specify a different SID Name that does not already exist.
Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.

Comment: @Trackres, did you start DCA second time? If yes you can remove all (software and database) and install it from zero. Or start with different SID

Comment: No i clicked retry button in installer. Tried to removing all software and services but it didnt helped.

Comment: Try to create database with new SID. Later you can (not easy) erase the existing database

Comment: So finally it worked, thank you for your help. I removed everything and during clear installation manually started oracle service as you said, and it worked. Previously, I started it too late.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - why are you recommending to remove the _software_ just because of a DBCA error?

Comment: @EdStevens, my intention was to speedup the process. And as OP do not have data in database the fastest way is to create new database or remove all and install from scratch

Comment: @RomeoNinov - but it is overkill to delete the software and have to re-install that.  Just clean up the database.